# Access VBA IF (X and Y) > 0 then

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm stumped on this one. I have some functioning VBA code in Access that looks like this.

```
If (intFrontLoaded And 2) > 0 Then boolFrontLoad(1) = True Else boolFrontLoad(1) = False
If (intFrontLoaded And 4) > 0 Then boolFrontLoad(2) = True Else boolFrontLoad(2) = False
If (intFrontLoaded And 8) > 0 Then boolFrontLoad(3) = True Else boolFrontLoad(3) = False
If (intFrontLoaded And 16) > 0 Then boolFrontLoad(4) = True Else boolFrontLoad(4) = False
If (intFrontLoaded And 32) > 0 Then boolFrontLoad(5) = True Else boolFrontLoad(5) = False
If (intFrontLoaded And 64) > 0 Then boolFrontLoad(6) = True Else boolFrontLoad(6) = False
```

I'm trying to figure out how the `(intFrontLoaded And X) > 0)` works.

I know what it does, I'm trying to figure out how, example:
If intFrontLoaded = 14 then boolFrontLoad(1), (2) and (3) will be true.
If intFrontLoaded = 28 then boolFrontLoad(2), (3) and (4) will be true.

I understand that 2+4+8 = 12 and 4+8+16 = 28, but how does `(intFrontLoaded And X) > 0)` do the calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`And` in this context is a [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator.  The test is checking for a single flag bit. Let's use your example of `intFrontLoaded = 14` with `If (intFrontLoaded And 4) > 0 Then`.

```
14 as bitflags is this: 0000 0000 0000 1110
4 is this:              0000 0000 0000 0010
```

The result of `And` is every bit that is the same.  In the example above, it's only the "flag" bit, 4. So, the result of the `And` operation is 4.

Now plug that back into the expression:

```
If 4 > 0 Then
```

So, it executes the "true" condition. If you'll notice, all of the tests are powers of 2. This is because when they are represented as binary, they'll only be only a single bit.

Basically, `intFrontLoaded` is storing a single boolean value for each of the bits being tested.  This was much more common in early computing when memory was at a premium and using all 16 bits to store a boolean was considered wasteful.

Note that you can simplify this to:

```
boolFrontLoad(1) = intFrontLoaded And 2
boolFrontLoad(2) = intFrontLoaded And 4
boolFrontLoad(3) = intFrontLoaded And 8
boolFrontLoad(4) = intFrontLoaded And 16
boolFrontLoad(5) = intFrontLoaded And 32
boolFrontLoad(6) = intFrontLoaded And 64
```

Answer (score 2):

The `And` operator is a bitwise AND operation - it compares the bits in each operand and returns the value where both operands have bits in common.

That said, your code would be much clearer written as:

```
boolFrontLoad(1) = (intFrontLoaded And 2) > 0
boolFrontLoad(2) = (intFrontLoaded And 4) > 0
boolFrontLoad(3) = (intFrontLoaded And 8) > 0
boolFrontLoad(4) = (intFrontLoaded And 16) > 0
boolFrontLoad(5) = (intFrontLoaded And 32) > 0
boolFrontLoad(6) = (intFrontLoaded And 64) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a `bitwise` operation. The logical `And` is performed bit per bit between `intFrontLoaded And X`. When `X` is a power of 2, say `2^a`, its binary representation is composed of zeros except a 1 on the (a+1)'th position (numbering the bits from the right to the left).

Therefore, `intFrontLoaded And 4` checks whether the third bit in `intFrontLoaded` is set. if the result is non-zero, the `IF` will succeed.

In your code `intFrontLoaded` is used as a bit-set, that is, a set of flags where each bit represents a flag for some boolean condition.